# Delegate Method not Working

Tags: objective-c, delegates, ios9, xcode7

I'm trying to implement a delegate method for my button ... I think I did everything correctly but do not understand why I can not make it work ... My button does not respond to any commands looks dead ... ...

My button is located in the ViewController "B" and the function it has to perform is located in the ViewController "A"

This is my code

**viewControllerB.h**

```
@protocol UNI_TableLoginDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)showPassw;

@end

@interface viewControllerB : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UNI_TableLoginDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**viewControllerB.m (here I connected the action button via my storyboard)**

```
@implementation viewControllerB
@synthesize  delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (IBAction)showReset:(id)sender {
    [delegate showPassw];    
}
```

**viewControllerA.m**

```
#import "viewControllerB.h"

    @interface viewControllerA () <UNI_TableLoginDelegate>

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        viewControllerB *tableLogin = [[viewControllerB alloc] init];
        tableLogin.delegate = self;

    }

    //Delegate Method
    -(void)showPassw {

        if (containerTable.frame.origin.y == 56) {
            NSLog(@"ssss");
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"hdhdh");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the value of `delegate` set? Using `@synthesize` has not been a good practice for many years, it is not needed, an instance variable with a prepended underscore "_" will automatically be generated. Best practice is not to use property iVars directly but rather with `self.`, `[self.delegate showPassw];`

Comment: how are you calling the viewCntoller B ? how are you setting the delegate ?  Are you using performSegue method ?

Comment: I deleted thesyntesize and adopted self.delegate as your suggestion but when I use the button still do not get no action

Comment: no I'm not using any perform the following ... I just wish the button to return a simple NSLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate in your ViewController A.

Let's say you have this method that calls right before dismissing the ViewController A:

```
-(void)dismissThisController{

 // you need to set the delegate value
 [self.delegate yourDelegateMethod:withValueYouWantToSend];

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
}
```

and in your View Controller B, you have this delegate method:

```
#pragma mark ViewController A delegate
-(void)yourDelegateMethod:(someType)value{
//receive your delegate value here
    }
```

Comment: I understand the way you described, and I think it's the same one that I used in my code right? All you have to do the button, which is located in viewController B, is in the code of viewController A

viewController A = code to be executed
viewController B = where is the button

Comment: can you please tell me how you are presenting the view controller B ?

Comment: i mean, how you are navigating from A to B ?

Comment: No then ... I do not have to navigate between two view controller ... I need the button located in viewControllerB delegate any action that presents in viewcontrollerA

Comment: delegate doesnt work that way. You can't set A delegate in B. You can only receive the A delegate that is set in A in B.

Comment: so if I needed a button in viewController face an action that is in viewcontrollerA how should I do?

Comment: think it like this: " you are in A, and you perform some action. You want this action to be accessed in B. So you set the delegate in A , and access it in B. "  You cant set the delegate once you move away from A. Whatever you do, you have to do it before you leave A.